# Problem with Hilbert Transform of $\operatorname{sgn}(t)$

Tags: cauchy-principal-value

I haven't found a duplicate question, but apologies in advance if this **is** a dup.

At the DSP SE we were asked about the Hilbert Transform of the unit step (you math guys call it the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) which is the sum of a constant and the [signum function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function)).  So I attempted to answer the question thus:

---

To integrate the convolution integral of the Hilbert transform, one must make use of the concept of the [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) (p.v.) of an integral with some kinda nasty infinity or singularity in it.

Hilbert Transform:

$$\begin{align}
\hat{x}(t) &\triangleq \mathscr{H}\Big\{ x(t) \Big\} \triangleq \frac{1}{\pi t} \ \circledast x(t) \\
\\
 &= \mathrm{p.v.} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\pi v} \ x(t-v) \mathrm{d}v \\
\\
 &= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int\limits_{-1/\epsilon}^{-\epsilon} \frac{1}{\pi v} \ x(t-v) \mathrm{d}v \ + \ \int\limits_{\epsilon}^{1/\epsilon} \frac{1}{\pi v} \ x(t-v) \mathrm{d}v \\
\end{align}$$

That's in general.  Now let $x(t)$ be the unit step function:

$$ x(t) = \tfrac{1}{2}\big(1 + \operatorname{sgn}(t)\big) = \begin{cases}
0 \qquad & t<0 \\
\tfrac12 \qquad & t=0 \\
1 \qquad & t>0 \\
\end{cases} $$

and the sign function $\operatorname{sgn}(t)$ is

$$ \operatorname{sgn}(t) \triangleq \begin{cases}
-1 \qquad & t<0 \\
\ \ 0 \qquad & t=0 \\
\ \ 1 \qquad & t>0 \\
\end{cases} $$

Because of the linearity of convolution and of the fact that the integral of a sum is the sum of integrals, we can think of this as the Hilbert transform of $\tfrac12$ added to the Hilbert transform of the sign function $\tfrac12 \operatorname{sgn}(t)$.

The Hilbert transform of $\tfrac12$ or of any constant is zero because the two integrals expressing the principal value above will be exact negatives for **any** value of $\epsilon$ in the limit.  So the problem is just that of the Hilbert transform of $\tfrac12 \operatorname{sgn}(t)$.

In the integral above, let's say $t>0$.  The math will be identical with flipped signs for the case $t<0$.  For $t=0$ there will simply be the problem of infinity.

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{H}\Big\{ \tfrac12 \operatorname{sgn}(t) \Big\} & = \frac12 \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \left( \int\limits_{-1/\epsilon}^{-\epsilon} \frac{1}{\pi v} \ \operatorname{sgn}(t-v) \mathrm{d}v \ + \ \int\limits_{\epsilon}^{1/\epsilon} \frac{1}{\pi v} \ \operatorname{sgn}(t-v) \mathrm{d}v \right) \\
\\
 & = \frac{1}{2\pi} \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \left( \int\limits_{-1/\epsilon}^{-t} \frac{1}{v} (+1) \mathrm{d}v \ + \ \int\limits_{-t}^{-\epsilon} \frac{1}{v} (+1) \mathrm{d}v \ + \ \int\limits_{\epsilon}^{t} \frac{1}{v} (+1) \mathrm{d}v \ + \ \int\limits_{t}^{1/\epsilon} \frac{1}{v} (-1)  \mathrm{d}v \right) \\
\end{align}$$

Wow!  This is problematic.  The two integrals in the interior cancel each other, but the two integrals on the outside team up

$$\begin{align}
 \mathscr{H}\Big\{ \tfrac12 \operatorname{sgn}(t) \Big\} &= \frac{1}{2\pi} \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \left( \int\limits_{-1/\epsilon}^{-t} \frac{+1}{v}  \mathrm{d}v \ + \ \int\limits_{t}^{1/\epsilon} \frac{-1}{v}  \mathrm{d}v \right) \\
\\
 &= \frac{1}{2\pi} \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} 2\int\limits_{t}^{1/\epsilon} \frac{-1}{v}  \mathrm{d}v \\
\\
 &= \frac{1}{\pi} \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \ -\big(\log(1/\epsilon) - \log(t)\big)  \\
\\
 &= \frac{1}{\pi} \big( \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \  \log(\epsilon) + \log(t) \big) \\
\end{align}$$

I don't see how that converges to a finite value.

---

But another person, using indirect means, appears to show that the answer is simply $\tfrac1\pi \log(|t|)$  but I cannot see how that can be true since I thought I was pretty careful with this principal value and the integrals with finite limits were all well-defined and exist.

Comment: For functions that don't decay at $\infty$, there's an alternative definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform#Hilbert_transform_of_bounded_functions

Comment: I've worked out the integrals in the second part of [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/49004/4298). The result is indeed $2/\pi \log(|t|)$ for the Hilbert transform of $\textrm{sgn}(t)$, and $1/\pi \log(|t|)$ for the Hilbert transform of the unit step.